# Multiply C++ template matrix

Tags: c++, templates, matrix

I have a matrix class defined this way:

```
template<int M, int N, typename T>
class Matrix
{
 typedef Matrix<M, N, T> MTYPE;
 /*...*/
};
```

I have to implement the matrix multiplication but I do not know how to do the operator overriding..

Something like

```
MTYPE operator *(MTYPE& m) { /*...*/ }
```

Would accept only a N*M matrix. So how can I overcome this problem?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve in the end? Are you really writing your own Matrix library? There are several libs out there.

Comment: `operator*=` doesn't make sense when you're fixing the matrix dimensions at compile time. An MxN * NxM matrix is MxM.

Comment: @eduffy: More useful would be to have `operator*=` specialize for N x N matrices.

Comment: Of course doesn't make sense, my mistake, I'm fixing it, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As has been pointed out in a comment, *= doesn't make sense for non-square matrices.

For the general case,

```
template<int M, int N, typename T>
class Matrix
{
    typedef Matrix<M, N, T> MTYPE;
    /*...*/
public:
    template<int L>
    Matrix<M,L,T> operator*(const Matrix<N,L,T>& second) const
    {
       Matrix<M,L,T> result;
       for(...)
           for(...)
               for(...)
                   // ...
       return result;
    }
};
```

Or, if you prefer, use a free function operator* with two parameters (and template arguments M,N,L, and T), and make it a friend of your matrix class.

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to create a templated operator, either inside or outside of the class.

For example, to multiply a N x M by a M x M you might want to do:

```
  template <int N, int M, class T>
  friend Matrix<N, M, T> operator*(const Matrix<N, M, T> &lhs, const Matrix<M, M, T> &rhs);
```

Other versions look similar. It'd probably most useful to define this outside of the class.

To multiply a (N1 x M) by (M x N2) you'd do:

```
 template<int N1, int N2, int M, class T>
 friend Matrix<N1, N2, T> operator*(const Matrix<N1, M, T> &lhs, const Matrix<M, N2, T> &rhs);
```

Comment: +1. It serves well to disambiguate the inner dimension, though, no need to use M both for the column count of the rhs and for the inner dimension.

Comment: why would you need different overloads?

Comment: @wolfgang: It depends really. Strictly speaking you don't need different ones, but you may use it for performance reasons if a specialized version could be written in a more efficient manner. One example would be a `Transpose` function. For square matrices, you could do it in place. For non-square you could do the naive "copy into transposed format".